# How to setup Angular routing on Tomcat?

Tags: angular, tomcat, routes

I'm using Tomcat to host angular application with router.
But when I try to use the routing I'm getting a 404 error (main/getting-started).

Tomcat is running on localhost:9443/main.

Router configuration:

```
 {path: 'getting-started', component: GettingStartedComponent},
 {path: '', component: codeComponent},
 {path: 'main', component: codeComponent}
```

Main works correctly.
And getting-started works on ng serve.

Tried this solution, didn't work: https://medium.com/@nithin.biliya/deploying-angular-application-on-tomcat-server-fixing-deep-linking-issue-577565fe303d

Tried different baseHref in angular config and in index.html.

According to https://angular.io/guide/deployment,

> Routed apps must fall back to index.html

> If the application uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

> A routed application should support "deep links".

Now, how can I set it up on tomcat?

Comment: As tomcat contain contextPath as `/main`. You won't assign `/main` in Angular any more. In this case your url should be `localhost:9443/main/main/getting-started` if your configuration be all right.

Comment: `localhost:9443/main/main/getting-started` didn't work as well. I also tried to change paths in angular before build like that `{path: 'getting-started', component: GettingStartedComponent},` and trying to access it with `localhost:9443/main/getting-started`  didn't help as well.

Comment: You need to look in to at Tomcat's configuration then.

Comment: Thank you. For me in the end it was both tomcat and angular configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who had a problem with this issue.
It is caused by

> If the application uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Solution that worked for me:

**In your eclipse project with angular build that is served on Tomcat:**

Inside META-INF folder edit a file context.xml and add RewriteValve:

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

If you don't have context.xml - create it and add the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

Inside WEB-INF, create file `rewrite.config` (this file contain the rule for URL Rewriting and used by tomcat for URL rewriting). Inside rewrite.config, copy the below content:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html
```

This will return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Now if the issue is not resolved -  depending on your project settings you might need to change baseHref in angular.json or change the RewriteRule.