# Can I execute angular app from the link in an e-mail

Tags: angular

I have an application based on github [Angular web app](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-10-signup-verification-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/account)

I have problem with the link I am sending to the registering user in an email which looks like this (inside the Microsoft outlook):

```
http://rejkid.hopto.org:8080/account/verify-email?token=CA9E3D9587D1884644F70F321AE29847B83D1014F6DCB2552B705B533D583C7A0CDBA57389D92C6C
```

It is supposed to run browser and activate the route to create angular component (`VerifyEmailComponent`) defined in my `AccountRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'verify-email', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
            { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
            { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

The `rejkid.hopto.org` is my computer name.
If I use instead of `rejkid.hopto.org` the localhost it work just fine, but using `rejkid.hopto.org` creates for some reason a problem.

I am running Tomcat as my web server (I tried ISS but I get the similar problem).

When I execute that link using `Postman` I get the error
`The requested resource [&#47;account&#47;verify-email] is not available</p> <p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists`.

So It seems to me the web server has problem locating "/account/verify-email" resource in my angular app, but the resource definitely exists because it is OK if I use `localhost` in my URL?.

Update:
It does not work with localhost in URL. It only works if I run ng serve from Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Think this needs a "catch-all, serve index.html instead" type of solution?

Comment: What exactly do you  mean?. Can you provide some more information please

Comment: I don't have any experience with TomCat, but you might want to use something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336941/how-to-setup-angular-routing-on-tomcat - Now it looks for a file `verify-email` inside folder `account`. That doesn't exists, so it throws a 404. What it should do is serve the `index.html`, and let angular handle the routing. `ng serve` does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

- You are trying to access the resource with `rejkid.hopto.org`. But your system doesn't know what `rejkid.hopto.org` is.
- You need to point the URL to the localhost.
- Add the below line in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file (For Windows)

  127.0.0.1    rejkid.hopto.org

Comment: I have used even localhost to test that. It still gives me an error 404. I have my DNS name rejkid.hopto.org defined. No matter which host I use it gives me the same error. Is there any documentation how can I open angular application from an e-mail link that points to it?

Comment: What do you get when going to the url 'http://rejkid.hopto.org:8080' in your browser

Comment: I get IIS home page

Answer (score 0):

check on this link https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fall-back-to-indexhtml.
Routed apps must fall back to index.html

A routed application should support "deep links". A deep link is a URL that specifies a path to a component inside the application. For example, example.com.com/heroes/42 is a deep link to the hero detail page that displays the hero with id: 42.

There is no issue when the user navigates to that URL from within a running client. The Angular router interprets the URL and routes to that page and hero.

But clicking a link in an email, entering it in the browser address bar, or merely refreshing the browser while on the hero detail page —all of these actions are handled by the browser itself, outside the running application. The browser makes a direct request to the server for that URL, bypassing the router.

A static server routinely returns index.html when it receives a request for example.com.com/. But it rejects example.com/heroes/42 and returns a 404 - Not Found error unless it is configured to return index.html instead.